# How to create Google Sheets file when CSV file is downloaded

Tags: google-apps-script

When a user downloads a CSV file from an arbitrary site, I would like to be informed of this event and automatically upload the same file as a Google Sheets file.  Is this possible or would this be violating a fundamental browser security concept?

The CSV file in question does not have a URL, but is created on the fly by the arbitrary web site, when the user clicks a button.  An example would be the user's list of financial transactions at a bank web site.

I am not new to Google Apps/Drive but I am new to Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to detect that kind of events.

I can't even imagine a function that would allow for automatic file upload of a local file... don't forget Google Apps Script is a server based environment.

Comment: I was hoping that since the download happens within the browser, it would be visible.  Sort of like Greasemonkey scripts.

Comment: Client side javascript is also useable in Google Apps Script using html service but it gets sanitized by caja and some functionalities are removed. I really doubt it can be done.

Comment: Thank you, enough to get me started.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Also, forgot to thank you for the almost immediate response you provided.  Thanks so much.